# unable to access cellIndex when passing in event Target ID JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to return the target event id cell index.

When I console log the output to test and pass in a static value for the target elements ID I am able to access the property fine, however, when I attempt to pass in the ID using the event object it returns undefined.

I am attempting to do this so I can then iterate over all rows of the cell, but only at the cellIndex position of each loop.

Note, the solution must be pure Javascript.

```
checkColWinFunc(target); 

function checkRowWinFunc(target) {

var colEleNum = document.getElementById(target); 
var colIndex = target.cellIndex; 

console.log(colIndex);   

//Below loop for when index is accessible.   
//grabbing tables element by ID.     
// var topRow = document.getElementById("gameSpace"); 

    /*
      for (x = 0; x <= 4 ;x++){
          console.log(colIndex); 
         }
    */
}
```

Comment: Show the code that's passing the ID using the event object. You probably have a bug there. Why don't you just pass the element itself, instead of using the ID?

Comment: I need to capture the element on click so I thought I would need the event object to do this.

Comment: Yes, you need the event object. You can get the target element from the event object, why do you need to use its ID?

Comment: Actually, your function seems to be confused about whether `target` is an ID or an element. `document.getElementById(target)` means it's the ID, but `target.cellIndex` means it's the element.

Comment: You are a star, this was enough to fix the bug. I was passing in the ID for no reason.

Comment: Thank you also Barmar, I have no idea why I thought I needed the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element that was clicked by passing `this` to your function.

```js
function checkRowWinFunc(target) {
    console.log("Here's the element that was clicked:");
    console.log(target);
}
```

```html
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="checkRowWinFunc(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I should not have been attempting to access the ID, the ID does not contain the property which I need, it is contained in the target element.